# Pass ruby String to jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I can pass a integer to jquery but I can't pass a string. Why?
Thanks!

**This works:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def view
        @number =2
    end

end
```

*view.html.erb:*

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var b = <%=@number%>;
        if(b == 2) {
            $('#modal-1').modal('show');
        }

    });
    </script>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def view
        @string = "string"
    end

end
```

*view.html.erb:*

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var b = <%=@string%>;
    if(b == 'string') {
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: You have stringr instead of string could that be it?

Comment: @volt does my answer answer the question?

Comment: Inspect the generated JS. You'll likely to find that the string is missing quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you have stringr instead of string, will this result in javascript like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var b = string;
    if(b == 'string') {
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
    }

});
```

If so, then it will look for a js variable called "string" and throw ReferenceError.

More generally, why are you templating javascript like this? Can't you use AJAX instead? This is liable to injection attacks?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var b = "<%= escape_javascript @word %>";
    if(b == "teste") {
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
    }

});
<%end%>
```

Comment: Code only answers usually benefit from some more explanation as to what's going on.

Comment: oh ok, sorry! I will complete